# Trying to Provision IAM Users in AWS IAM with the AWS-CDK

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

I am attempting to provision IAM users with the AWS-CDK. I'm currently having an issue with provisioning a temporary password for the user I am creating and am trying to find a way around using secrets manager as I think there should be easier ways to do this. Here is the code I have below (the password prop I pass to the "CisUser" is currently erroring out):

```
import cdk = require('@aws-cdk/core')
import * as logs from '@aws-cdk/aws-logs';
import s3 = require("@aws-cdk/aws-s3");
import * as cloudtrail from '@aws-cdk/aws-cloudtrail';
import cloudwatch = require('@aws-cdk/aws-cloudwatch');
import { User, Group } from "@aws-cdk/aws-iam";
import * as lambda from "@aws-cdk/aws-lambda"
import path = require('path');
import events = require("@aws-cdk/aws-events");
import * as targets from "@aws-cdk/aws-events-targets";
import { SecretValue } from '@aws-cdk/core';


export class CloudComplianceUserBaselineStack extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
      super(scope, id, props);
    
      const CisUser = new User(this, 'CisUser',{
          userName: 'CisUser',
          password: 'testPassword12345%$',
          passwordResetRequired: true,
      })
      const TestUser = new iam.User(this,"TestUser",{})
      const adminGroup = new iam.Group(this, 'AdminGroup',{
        managedPolicies: [
          iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName("AdministratorAccess")
        ]
      })
      const AuditGroup = new iam.Group(this,'AuditGroup',{
        managedPolicies:[
          iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName("ReadOnlyAccess")
        ]
      })
      AuditGroup.addUser(CisUser)
      adminGroup.addUser(TestUser)
      
      
    }}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that we should use the exact type when trying to pass the password field

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-iam-readme.html

```js
import { SecretValue } from '@aws-cdk/core';
...
...
{
    password: SecretValue.plainText('testPassword12345%$'),

}
```

Comment: When the user changes it, how should I change my code then? It seems redundant to provision user's in code with a temp password such as this

Comment: I'm thinking we just generate a temp password at init time - when the Stack runs a new user created - we just give this information for the user ( the password should generate by some PATTERN ) - The user can change the password after that if they want

The Stack create the user should separate and maybe we will have another stack RESET PASSWORD STACK in case the user forgot the PASS in the future.

Comment: @aroe that's a different question. This answer answers your original question.